# Retrieve JSON from URL and convert it to Cloud Firestore Collection with Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Here is what I want to achieve : I want to get a JSON on a daily basis from a URL and convert it to a cloud firestore collection in order to be able to use it in my Flutter app. Ideally, the script would only add new data to the collection.

I saw that I can use `scheduler` from Firebase cloud functions to run tasks daily. That's not the problem for now.

However, I don't know how to use Firebase cloud functions properly to get data from URL and convert it to collection. Maybe that's not the point of cloud functions and I misunderstood something. So first question : **Can I run classic nodeJS stuff inside cloud functions? I suppose I can**

Next, I initialized a cloud function project locally, connected it to my Google account and started to write code into `index.js`.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const db = admin.firestore();
const collectionToiletRef = db.collection('mycollection');

let settings = { method: "Get" };

let url = "my-url.com"

fetch(url, settings)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
        print(json);
        // TODO for each json object, add new document
    });
```

Second question : **How can I run this code to see if it works ?** I saw that emulator can be used but how can I check visually my cloud firestore collection ? On this simple example, I only want to print my json to see if I can get the data correctly. Where would the printing be done ?

Maybe cloud functions is not what I need for this task. Maybe my code is bad. I don't know. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

I tried this but the call never ends. I think it's waiting for a promise that never returns or something like that.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.tempoCF = functions
    .firestore.document('/tempo/{docId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        console.log("onCreate");

        let settings = { method: "Get" };

        let url = "https://opendata.paris.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=sanisettesparis&q=&rows=-1"
        try {
            let response = await fetch(url, settings);
            let json = await response.json();
            // TODO for each json object, add new document
            await Promise.all(json["records"].map(toiletJsonObject => {
                return db.collection('toilets').doc(toiletJsonObject["recordid"]).set({}); // Only to create documents, I will deal with the content later
            }));
        }
        
        catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }
    }
    );
```

This code works and create all the documents I want but never return. However, the `async (snap, context) => {}` passed to `onCreate` is a Promise. And this promise ends when `Promise.all` ends. I'm missing something but I don't know why. I'm struggling a lot with async programming with Dart or JS. Not very clear in my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I run classic nodeJS stuff inside cloud functions?

Sure! Since the fetch method returns a Promise you can very well use it in a background triggered or a scheduled Cloud Function.

> How can I run this code to see if it works?

Your code will work perfectly in the [emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite), but you will need to trigger the Cloud Function with one of the Firebase services that can run in the emulator. For example you can trigger the Cloud Function by creating a document in the Firestore emulator console.

The following Cloud Function will do the trick: just create a doc in a dummy `tempo` collection and the CF will add a new doc in a `newDocs`collection. It's up to you to adapt the fields values for this doc, I've just used the entire JSON object.

```
exports.tempoCF = functions
    .firestore.document('/tempo/{docId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        let settings = { method: "Get" };

        let url = "https://..."

        return fetch(url, settings)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                console.log(json);
                // TODO for each json object, add new document

                return admin.firestore().collection('newDocs').add(json);

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                return null;
            });
    });
```

---

You could also deploy your Cloud Function to the Firebase backend, and if you want to schedule it, just change the code as follows (change the trigger):

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {

        let settings = { method: "Get" };

        let url = "https://..."

        return fetch(url, settings)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                console.log(json);
                // TODO for each json object, add new document

                return admin.firestore().collection('newDocs').add(json);

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                return null;
            });
    });
```

---

**Edit following your edit:**

The following code does work correctly in the emulator, creating docs in the `toilets` collection.

```
exports.tempoCF = functions.firestore
    .document('/tempo/{docId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        console.log('onCreate');

        let settings = { method: 'Get' };

        let url =
            'https://opendata.paris.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=sanisettesparis&q=&rows=-1';
        try {
            let response = await fetch(url, settings);
            let json = await response.json();

            return Promise.all(   // Here we return the promise returned by Promise.all(), so the life cycle of the CF is correctly managed
                json['records'].map((toiletJsonObject) => {
                    admin
                        .firestore()
                        .collection('toilets')
                        .doc(toiletJsonObject['recordid'])
                        .set({ adresse: toiletJsonObject.fields.adresse });
                })
            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thx, i'll try that ! But why do I need to encapsulate the code into a CF ? There is no way to run NodeJS function outside the CF ? Also, I thought that the `export` things was to create an endpoint that is callable via http request. Will the exported function run automatically when I execute the JS file in the emulator ? Finally, is there a way to create like a factory from JSON that only add new records to Firestore or do I need to do that manually ?

Comment: I managed to make the emulator work thank you. However, when I start the emulator, it runs the `index.js` and I suppose create an endpoint for tempoCF but this function isn't called. How can I run it manually before testing the scheduled function ? I have to call something like http://localhost:5001/tempoCF ?

Comment: "do I need to encapsulate the code into a CF" => Yes, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_. Is there a way to create like a factory from JSON => You can use any JavaScript/TypeScript code or library to generate objects that you use to create Firestore docs.

Comment: "How can I run it manually before testing the scheduled function ?" => I gave an example with a Firestore trigger in my answer (`tempo` collection). You could trigger it in the emulator as an [HTTP Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions#instrument_your_app_for_https_functions_emulation) but since you are going to deploy it as a Scheduled Function, I would recommend using a background trigger as the code will be the same than for a schedule one.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I edited my code as there is something I don't understand with async functions if you mind take a look at it.

Comment: You should do `return Promise.all(json["records"].map(toiletJsonObject => db.collection('toilets').doc(toiletJsonObject["recordid"]).set({});));` since you need to return a Promise to correctly manage the life cycle of the CF. Please upvote and update my answer if it solved your problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't complete either :/ The terminal doesn't allow me to run new functions. I need to press CTRL+C.